# Do I need to use title="" in this situation of HTML5?

Tags: html

When defining a title or alt to an anchor tag, which is valid HTML5?

Is it best to define both, or only one?

Does it affect SEO at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in HTML, even from version 4, the `title` attribute is valid for almost all elements. `alt` is different in that it's only valid for images, the idea being to provide a text only alternative version of the image, which would be useful to people with visual impairment (as they'd be able to hear their browser read the text)

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to provide an alt attribute for images, even if you're going to leave an empty string ( "" ). The alt attribute helps improve accessibility for screen readers since the user most likely can't see the image with which it's associated. The title is less useful for accessibility purposes but is still a good practice to get into.

Comment: What about for anchors surrounding text, not images?

Comment: Alt attributes aren't necessary for anchors tags because they're not alternate content for them. You can use a title to help assist a user with a tooltip before they decide to click on a link, but alt is for images.